# Why isn't this simple object having its Id property set after insert with OrmLite and Sqlite (C#)

Tags: c#, sqlite, ormlite

I'm just experimenting with Ormlite for Sqlite at the moment, and have hit a problem - this code, simple as it is, doesn't seem to update.

Here's a simple test class:

```
class Person
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public Person()
    {
    }

    public Person(string firstname, string surname) : this()
    {
        FirstName = firstname;
        Surname = surname;
    }

}
```

and the Ormlite code:

```
OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider = SqliteDialect.Provider;

using (IDbConnection db = "c:/temp/test.sqlite".OpenDbConnection())
{
    db.DropAndCreateTable<Person>();

    var p = new Person("bob", "smith");

    // p.Id property not being set in this Insert
    db.Insert(p);

    p.FirstName = "robert";

    db.Update<Person>(p);
```

Update: I've discovered that after the first insert, the Person.Id property is not being updated to the autoincremented value, and when manually set, the update does work. So, do I need to manually set the Id with `p.Id = (int) db.GetLastInsertId();` every time I insert a new record?